# What does this mean " first_match = bool(text) and pattern[0] in {text[0], '.'} " ? This is the regular expression matching question in python

Tags: python-3.x

```
    def match(text, pattern):
        if not pattern: return not text
        first_match = bool(text) and pattern[0] in {text[0], '.'}
        return first_match and match(text[1:], pattern[1:])
```

I'm new to python and I don't understand the syntax. What is the purpose of elements in braces and what does "bool(text) and pattern[0] in {text[0], '.'}"

Comment: This is indicating a set of elements

Answer (score 1):

In python, braces are used to create either a dictionary, or a set.

```
    my_set = {1, 2, 3}
    my_dict = {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3}
```

`bool(text) and pattern[0] in {text[0], '.'}` is checking whether the text is true (i.e. not empty or false), and the first element in pattern is either equal to text[0] or is a '.'

Answer (score 1):

If we were to destruct your function into distinct pieces, it will be easier to understand

```py
def match(text: str, pattern: str) -> bool:
    # if pattern is an empty string or None
    if not pattern:
        # True if text is empty string or None, otherwise - false
        result: bool = not text
        return result

    # If text is empty or None return False
    if not text:
        return False

    # Equivalent to set(first letter of text, dot)
    # We use set/{} instead of list/[] or tuple/() to remove duplicates, 
    # however i don't see why should we care about duplicated dots here
    subset: set = {text[0], '.'}

    # If first letter of pattern is not in subset, return False
    if pattern[0] not in subset:
       return False

    # Go one level deeper in recursion and return it's answer
    result: bool = match(text[1:], pattern[1:])
    return result
```

About curly braces. In python they mean two things:

- [dict / dictionary](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries): `{"foo": "bar", "count": 10}`
- [set / unique list](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#sets): `{1, 2, 3, 3}` will create set `{1, 2, 3}`

Follow the links to learn more from python's docs